# switch case value passing not working when i execute if condition

Tags: php, switch-statement

This is the code I am using to display the dropdown value:

```
 switch ($_POST['input_102']) {
     case 14:
            $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Priority mail (domestic/US only)   <span>$14.00</span></li> ';
        break;
     case 40:
            $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Courier/Express (domestic/US only) <span>$40.00</span></li> ';
        break;
     case 14:
             $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Air Mail (overseas/international) <span>$14.00</span></li> ';
         break;
     case 80:
            $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Courier/Express (overseas/international) <span>$80.00 </span></li> ';
         break;
 }
```

Here I faced one issue in that I have two values like 14.
  So I changed the code like this. It executes but when the if case executes it shows nothing while the else case shows a result:

```
 switch ($_POST['input_102']) {
       case 14:
             //custom code
            if($_POST['input_13']=='United States'){
                $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Priority mail (domestic/US only)   <span>$14.00</span></li> ';
             }else{
                $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Air Mail (overseas/international) <span>$14.00</span></li> ';
             }
              //custom code end 

           break;
       case 40:
             $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Courier/Express (domestic/US only) <span>$40.00</span></li> ';
           break;

       case 80:
             $mailling=$mailling.'<li>Courier/Express (overseas/international) <span>$80.00 </span></li> ';
           break;
  }
```

I printed the  $_POST['input_13']  and it's value is United States. Why am I not getting the result for the if case.

Comment: do you need to call else condition?

Comment: no depend on $_POST['input_13'] contry name it will print .. if it is US it will be print if Case or else @raheelshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

`if($_POST['input_13']==='United States'){`

The three equal signs bring more precision.

The another way is this:

`if($_POST["input_13"]=="United States"){`

With double quotes, but this doesn't impact very much, but test equal.

In general for me Your code it's perfect but, the server sometimes doesnt work right.